# Is there a way to check if user HAS SHARED my fanpage on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, share

I am wondering is there a way to check if user has shared fanpage on Facebook.

I need this for an facebook App: user has to share it (application fanpage) first, then he gets the full access to the app.

The easiest way would be creating custom share button and after that put data in the database. Cool.
But what if user has already done it, before he came to my app page?

Do you guys know any way to do that (in PHP would be nice)?

On the internet I've found tips only about checking page was liked.

Comment: Incentivizing sharing is not allowed according to the Facebook Platform Policy. But it is also impossible to do if breaking the policy wasn't enough to stop you

Comment: Please use the search of StackOverflow next time first. There are dozens of similar questions. And NO, this is no longer allowed as @WizKid said, and also no longer possible with Graph API v2.1